# PSQL return only value from jsonb_each

Tags: postgresql

I'm calling `jsonb_each_text` and it is working exactly as I expect, returning me this:

```
select jsonb_each_text('{"text": "this is text", "text2": "this is text2", "f_id": "21"}') as line;
          line           
-------------------------
 (f_id,21)
 (text,"this is text")
 (text2,"this is text2")
(3 rows)
```

I know that I can easily return just the keys by doing this:

```
select jsonb_object_keys('{"text": "this is text", "text2": "this is text2", "f_id": "21"}') as line;
 line  
-------
 f_id
 text
 text2
(3 rows)
```

Is there a way I can only return the values?

So for example, I'd like this as my output:

```
          line           
-------------------------
21
"this is text"
"this is text2"
```

The values don't need to be unique or anything.

I haven't been able to find an equivalent to `jsonb_object_keys` for values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as a proper set returning function:

```
select t.value
from jsonb_each_text('{"text": "this is text", "text2": "this is text2", "f_id": "21"}') as t(key, value);
```